# Converting Single dimensional matrix to two dimension in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Well I do not know if I used the exact term. I tried to find an answer on the net.
Here is what i need:
I have a matix

```
                              a = 1  4  7 

                                  2  5  8

                                  3  6  9
```

If I do a(4) the value is 4. So it is reading first column top to buttom then continuing to next .... I don't know why. However,

What I need is to call it using two indices. As row and column:

```
                                  a(1,2)= 4
```

or even better if i can call it in the following way:

```
                                  a{1}(2)=4
```

What is this process really called (want to learn) and how to perform in matlab.
I thought of a loop. Is there a built in function
Thanks a lot

Check this:
a =

```
18    18    16    18    18    18    16     0     0     0
16    16    18     0    18    16     0    18    18    16
18     0    18    18     0    16     0     0     0    18
18     0    18    18    16     0    16     0    18    18

>> a(4)
  ans =
  18

>> a(5)
  ans =
  18

>> a(10)
  ans =
  18
```

I tried reshape. it is reshaping not converting into 2 indeces

Comment: That doesn't look like a vector to me.

Comment: what is it @Oli? I said before I do not know if I am using the right terms

Comment: It looks like a matrix to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already got a matrix, you already can access it with two indices:

if you've got

```
                          a = 1  4  7 

                              2  5  8

                              3  6  9
```

you can access it as

```
 a(3,2) = 6
```

However, the indexing goes from the top left, row first then column.  If you want to get at the "4" in the matrix then do:

```
a(1,2)
```

Comment: you are right @Nate well I tried that it didn't work now yes it is working. But how come if it is a matrix with 2 indeces accepting a(1)!!

Comment: That's just one of the features of Matlab :) .  Accessing it via one index will grab the value as if you stacked the columns into a vector.

Comment: To elaborate on @Nate's comment - one reason matrices support both `A(i,j,k)` indexing and `A(i)` indexing is so you can still loop over every element without needing to nest loops. For example, `for i = 1:product(size(A))`. Mind you, most MATLAB functions accept matrix input, so you should never have to do this in practice - but you **can**. ;)

Comment: Also commit to memory: "Matrices in MATLAB are in row-major order. Matrices in MATLAB are in row-major order. Matrices in MATLAB are..."

Answer (score 1):

To reshape a vector/matrix/array, use [`reshape()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html).

Answer (score 0):

Or you could leave it as a one dimensional array and just use

`((Column - 1) * 3) + Row - 1)` as the index. 3 because there are three columns.

NB a(4) = 4 because of the way you've arranged columns and rows in the one dimensional array, yours is "loaded" as

R1C1,R2C1,R3C1, R1C2 etc wher R is row and C is column
If that's inconvenient then you just need to get whatever fills the array row then column so the above mapping would be

```
((Row - 1) * 3) + Column - 1)
```

Don't do Matlab so above code assumes array starts at 0, if not just add 1 to it.

Comment: so how to convert? I want to call it to be used by other function which is using the two dimensional convention

Comment: The above is the conversion. GetValue(Row,Col) = a[((Col-1) * 3) + Row - 1)

Comment: Good general-purpose advice, but MATLAB has special syntax for indexing into N-dimensional matrices - so dirty tricks like this aren't necessary. Ain't it nice to use a high-level language? ;)

Comment: Nothing dirty about this trick, how do you think a rectangular array is arranged anyway? Learnt it in 1975....

Comment: col as in column argument or variable.